# Building OpenCV 3.0.0-beta contrib text sample application

Tags: opencv3.0

I am trying to build the sample applications from opencv-3.0.0-beta with opencv_contrib-3.0.0-beta.

Here is what I have done

1. Downloaded and unzipped: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/3.0.0-beta to /home/me/opencv
2. Downloaded and unzipped https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/3.0.0-beta to /home/me/opencv
3. mkdir /home/me/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build
4. cd /home/me/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build
5. cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/me/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.0.0-beta/modules /home/me/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-beta
6. make -j5

The above works perfectly, no errors.

However I was expecting the sample applications to build, the only one I really care about is: /home/me/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.0.0-beta/modules/text/

I have tried building it with the following steps

1. cd /home/me/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.0.0-beta/modules/text/
2. sudo cmake .

However I get an error, here is the output I get!

> -- Tesseract:   NO CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (ocv_define_module):   Unknown CMake command "ocv_define_module".
>
> CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:   No cmake_minimum_required
>   command is present.  A line of code such as
>
> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
> ```
>
> should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may
>   be lower   if you wish to support older CMake versions for this
>   project.  For more   information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question answered [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/issues/209). Thank you mshanuin!